# Nodal voltage with a current source

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider, current-source, nodal-analysis

I'm trying to understand the behavior of the circuit below containing both voltage and current sources.

I don't really see how can we get 30 V at the node in the middle when we have only 20 V voltage sources. I assume this would be the effect of the current source...

Does anyone know how to analyze the circuit analytically to get the 30 V? I tried it without success.

[image]

Comment: An ideal current source can produce an infinite voltage.

Comment: "Without success" doesn't help us to help you. Show the steps you tried and we can see where you went wrong.

Comment: @Finbarr, So would you say that this situation (having 30 V at middle node) would not be realistic if I had a non-ideal current source?

Comment: @Finbarr, Right, I should've added more details. Basically, I did a simple analysis where I said current will only be coming from the current source and divided equally between left and right since we have no voltage difference between left and right. This leads to V_R1 = V_R2 = 10*1 V and because current comes from current source only, voltage at middle node should be higher than left or right nodes. Hence, 30 V!!

Comment: "Voltage source" should really be called a "fixed voltage" because in circuits like this the power is actually flowing *into* the so-called source. If it helps, you can imagine a battery getting recharged.

Comment: Whether a current source can produce 30V depends on how it's designed and how much power it has available. All practical sources will have a finite range of operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, using KCL we can see that:

$$0=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_{\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}\tag1$$

The voltage across the resistors is given by Ohm's law:

- $$\text{I}_{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_{\text{e}_3}}{\text{R}_2}\tag2$$
- $$\text{I}_{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_{\text{e}_3}}{\text{R}_2}\tag3$$

So, we get:

$$0=2+\frac{20-\text{V}_{\text{e}_3}}{10}+\frac{20-\text{V}_{\text{e}_3}}{10}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{V}_{\text{e}_3}=30\space\text{V}\tag4$$